FormulaEvaluatorFormulaParseException Dotted range (full row or column) expression 'C.aRG' must have exactly 2 dots
I am using Apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSF to read from an Excel file and evaluate the formulas using:
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateAll();

A FormulaParseException is thrown with this message:
Dotted range (full row or column) expression 'C.aRG' must have exactly 2 dots.

This is due to cells being parsed as column names because they have 3 letters.
Is there a way to evaluate the cell without having to change its name?
A similar question can be found here but with no answer: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65963#c0

In spreadsheet formulas A..B is just an alternate syntax for A:B. And C as well as ARG both are valid column letters in current Excel sheets. So C..ARG would mean C:ARG. Thus formula parser reads C.aRG as a wrong syntax. I doubt Apache POIs formula parser is the only one which gets struggled by names which look like references, even if Excel itself tolerates them. I would simply try to avoid such names.

Is there a way to evaluate the cell without having to change its name or do I have to use another library?
