Excel cell not updated correctly
I am using apache-poi to modify an excel cell (with setCellValue) and retrieve the value of cellM14 whose value depends on the modified cell.
When I manually open excel cellM14 is updated properly but when I try to print it
System.out.println("Updated Value at M14: " + cellM14.getNumericCellValue());
the old value of cellM14 is printed. I cannot use Formula Evaluator since there is a bug with naming, see:
FormulaEvaluatorFormulaParseException Dotted range (full row or column) expression 'C.aRG' must have exactly 2 dots.
Can anyone help so that I can print the updated cellM14 please?
String filePath = "file";
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("input");
            workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

            // Check if Row 13 exists and print original value if the cell exists
            Row row13 = sheet.getRow(13);
            if (row13 != null) {
                Cell cellM14 = row13.getCell(11);
                if (cellM14 != null) {
                    System.out.println("Original Value at M14: " + cellM14.getNumericCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell M14 is null.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Row 13 is null.");
            }

            // Change the value in cell H5 (row index 4, column index 7)
            Row row4 = sheet.getRow(4);
            if (row4 == null) {
                row4 = sheet.createRow(4);
            }
            Cell sub = row4.getCell(7);
            if (sub == null) {
                sub = row4.createCell(7);
            }
            sub.setCellValue("nanoparticle");

            // Save workbook
            try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath))) {
                workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)) {
            workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
            try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath))) {
                workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            }
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("input");

            // Check if Row 13 exists and print original value if the cell exists
            Row row13 = sheet.getRow(13);
            if (row13 != null) {
                Cell cellM14 = row13.getCell(11);
                if (cellM14 != null) {
                    System.out.println("Updated Value at M14: " + cellM14.getNumericCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell M14 is null.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Row 13 is null.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


Apache-POI doesn't work like Excel. When you open Excel, M14 is updated because the workbook triggers recalculation automatically. But if you set the value of a cell on which M14 depends without recalculating via Apache POI, the get will still show the old value - Excel would do the same actually, if recalculation wasn't triggered. You should revaluate the cell using FormulaEvaluator to get the right result

The only problem is that I cannot use FormulaEvaluator due to a naming bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78651059/formulaevaluatorformulaparseexception-dotted-range-full-row-or-column-expressi . Is there any other way to do this?

Contribute a fix to the project for the naming bug you're facing? Pay someone else to fix it for you?

I eventually found a way, by using a VB SCRIPT to save the .xslx file and the formulas are now evaluated properly when accessing the M14 cell (even though it's not the most optimal solution it does the job).
